# mysqli Fails When Executing Multiple Queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to gather some information from a MySQL database and am having some issues. I can execute either of my two queries independently, but when I try to execute them both my code fails with the error `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /api/boxes.php on line 20` where Line 20 is `$queryFacet = $db->prepare("SELECT item_name FROM kf_facet_items WHERE id IN (SELECT facet_value_id FROM kf_box_data WHERE box_id = ?)");`

Here is my code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT b.id, b.ownerID, b.transactionID, b.post_date, b.description FROM kf_boxes b JOIN kf_box_data d ON b.id = d.box_id");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($id, $owner, $transactionID, $post_date, $description);

while ($query->fetch()) {
    $result['id'] = $id;
    $result['transaction'] = $transactionID;
    $result['post_date'] = $post_date;
    $result['description'] = $description;
    $queryFacet = $db->prepare("SELECT item_name FROM kf_facet_items WHERE id IN (SELECT facet_value_id FROM kf_box_data WHERE box_id = ?)");
    $queryFacet->bind_param('s',$id);
    $queryFacet->execute();
    $queryFacet->bind_result($item_name);
        while ($queryFacet->fetch()) {
            $facets['name'] = $item_name;
            $result['facets'] = $facets;
        }
    $output[] = $result;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on what is causing this and more importantly, how to solve it?

Comment: You are not doing any error checking, so you won't see why the query fails.

Comment: @popnoodles Wouldn't that pose a problem when executing that query on its own though? Which it doesn't.

Comment: @popnoodles Sure same error, but different means to getting it. As well as the fact that no answer was provided that solved the problem of the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I wasn't closing my first statement, which threw mysqli for a tizzy. Adding `$query->close();` after the while statement, then adding a for loop for the 2nd query worked as expected.